# Unable to pass a variable to Paraview script

Tags: python, paraview

I have the following bash script

```sh
for f in C:/folder/inside/my_stuff/*; do
    cd "$f" && 
    for file in *.ply; do
        "C:\\Program Files\\ParaView 4.4.0\\bin\\paraview.exe" --script="C:\\folder\\inside\\my_stuff\\screens2.py" $file
    done
done
```

The script is supposed to load .ply files into Paraview and then execute a number of commands, but I need to pass `$file` to the Python script so it would know which file to open.

The beginning of my script looks like this:

```
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
import numpy as np
import glob
import sys
#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

files = sys.argv[1]
```

But when I run the script I get an error:

```
File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

So the variable is not passed to the script. Oddly, the .ply file does load into Paraview but none of the commands are executed. I tried `sys.argv[0]`, `sys.argv[2]`, `sys.argv[3]`, `sys.argv[file]`, `sys.argv['file']`, but nothing works.

Comment: I think the issue here is a bit more fundamental than that. From the error message I'm guessing that however paraview runs the python script you give it doesn't even support passing parameters to it.

Comment: @John Kugelman If I remove $file from the bash script that you decided to remove from my comment my .ply files don't even load to Paraview, so the variable itself exists in some form. So why can't I pass it to Python? Everything that I googled seems to suggest that it should work.

Comment: What about an ugly hack using environment variables? `export` a fixed variable name, such as `MYAPP_PARAVIEW_FILE`, each loop iteration. This should be available to your script (unless the binary does user switch magic). Alternatively, and I most certainly may be wrong here, the [docs](https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/python/quick-start.html) seem to imply a method of running your Python script directly rather than through the executable client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ParaView does not forward arguments to script. Unknown command line arguments are interpreted as file to open in ParaView.

Depending on what you want to do, you should either:

- use pvpython executable instead of paraview one (if you don't need to use the GUI by yourself)

```
"C:\\Program Files\\ParaView 4.4.0\\bin\\pvpython.exe" "C:\\folder\\inside\\my_stuff\\screens2.py" $file
```

- put the `for` loop inside your script and reset session between each file